# Resolve setListAdapter and SimpleCursorAdapter deprecated

Tags: android

I am building a todo list android app that user `sqldb` to save data and `Listview` to display them. I am able to save the input but unable to display them. `setListAdapter` and `SimpleCursorAdapter` are deprecated that can be a reason.

```
public void updateUI() {

    ListView listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_todo) ;
    Cursor cursor;
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse(TaskContract.TaskEntry.TABLE),
            new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE,
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TIME,
            TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE},null,null,null);
    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    String[] columns = new String[]{TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TITLE, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_DATE, TaskContract.TaskEntry.COL_TASK_TIME};
    int [] id_column = new int[]{ R.id.task_title, R.id.task_date, R.id.task_time};

    SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_todo, cursor, columns, id_column);
    listview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: The adapter isn't deprecated.  The constructor you're using is deprecated.  You should include the flags. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html#CursorAdapter(android.content.Context, android.database.Cursor, int)

Comment: Sorry but i cant understand. can you show the make the etiquette edit and show please.

Comment: And edit isn't needed.  The SimpleCursorAdapter has two constructors.  The second one has an extra parameter that is a "flags" parameter which is defined in the CursorAdapter class. The one you are using in this question is using the first constructor which is deprecated.

Comment: i am new to android

Comment: the 2 option i get with SimpleCursorAdapter are android.widget and android.support.v4.widget which one should i choose

Answer (score 3):

> setListAdapter and SimpleCursorAdapter are depricated

`setListAdapter()` is not deprecated.

The specific `SimpleCursorAdapter` constructor that you are using is deprecated. Change:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_todo, cursor, columns, id_column);
```

to:

```
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.item_todo, cursor, columns, id_column, 0);
```

`startManagingCursor()` has deprecated for **over five years**. I do not know what you are using for books or training, but they are much too old. Get something written in 2014 or newer.

Managed cursors (`startManagingCursor()`, etc.) have been replaced by [`CursorLoader` and the loader framework](https://developer.android.com/training/load-data-background/setup-loader.html).

Comment: i am very new to android so dont know that much. can you please tell me how to do the appropriate changes and use CursorLoader and the loader framework.